# Laptop not booting after reset and battery not charging

Tags: laptop, battery, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS i7 series laptop.
After the factory reset, my PC is not booting normally. I have to use the power button a few times to start the laptop. I have noticed that the battery is not getting charged, it shows 0% available plugged in, charging.

What could be the reason for this? Do I need to replace the battery?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing one or more drivers for your hardware devices.
It sometimes happens that the Windows image stored by the manufacturer for Reset
is missing some parts.

Go in the manufacturer's website into the Support section for your computer
model, and check if you have all the drivers for your Windows version.
Reinstalling too many drivers doesn't hurt, except if you use the wrong one.
If several versions have the same name but differ in date, install only
the latest one.

Comment: I have updated the drivers from ASUS, the problem still persists. It is being noticed that the charging is active on the toolbar, I can see the battery icon is going up and down. Once the laptop is ready to use or finish booting, the icon stops moving.

Comment: See if *PC Settings >  Update & Security* has any updates now. If not, try the Windows Troubleshooting. If still no go, try `sfc /scannow`.

Comment: I have tried that as well, the output is `C:\Windows\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Comment: Faced with an unexplained Windows problem, you might do [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), which will refresh Windows without causing damage. But take good backups.

Comment: My Windows version is 8.1, upgrading to version 10 would be a good idea?

Comment: It would always be a good idea to upgrade to Windows 10, as it is better and safer. However, you would need to buy a serial number, if you have never before updated to Windows 10 on this computer.

Comment: Thanks, harrymc, will try that. Meanwhile, I have raised a ticket with ASUS

Comment: I had met the support person; he is of the opinion that the booting problem while doing re-start could be of hard disk or motherboard? What do you reckon?

Comment: And battery need a replacement as per his to advise

Comment: I'm always suspicious of someone advising the replacement of most of the computer. But if they are willing to pay for it, then go ahead.

Comment: Warranty period had expired, if hard disk is it culprit, then I have to pay, same the case with the motherboard

Comment: Instead of replacing part after part in the search for the problem, a good repair-shop might be more economical, since they will not make you pay for their components that they tried in your computer and taken back.